# Android MockWebServer dispatcher problems

Tags: android, mockwebserver

In my `MockWebServer` I'm using two different dispatcher. One `LocalResponseDispatcher` for locally add response and a normal `QueueDispatcher` in order to enqueue some stub responses. I had problem to switch between twos. Infact when I'm trying to use `.setDispatcher()` the webserver answer always with the response of the previous one. Have you got same issues ?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue. Every test worked separately, but for more than one only the first did his job. I found out, that my problem lied in different place. When you use MockWebServer remember, that if you execute in `@Before` method
`mockWebServer.url()` the port for your API is almost always different for every test. Port number in the url changes, eg. from http://localhost:58919/
to http://localhost:52915/

My problem was that I instantiated my APIs with url only once. It is usually good idea, because your API url doesn't change during your app work. Solution is to provide `setBaseUrl(String url)` to `TestApplication extends Application` (with appropriate custom jUnit runner) which recreate your API in the end: in my example, I reinstantiated Retrofit and API - tests started working like a charm.

Comment: You have also not to use okHttp cache or any other caching mechanism when you use mockwebserver, in my case this was the problem.

Comment: @lupsyn publish it as your response then :)